# Balancing the weights of the vertices of a graph by averaging along the edges.

Tags: graph-theory, puzzle

Suppose that you have a graph, and someone assigned real numbers to every vertex. You can modify these numbers by replacing the numbers on two adjacent vertices by their average. Your goal is to reach (in finitely many steps) a configuration where the same number is assigned to every vertex.

**My question is**, whether you can achieve your goal for every initial assignment of reals, where the graph is a triangle plus an edge? (4 vertices)

I do not know the answer to the problem, the question is a known and not easy problem when the graph is the 8-cycle. I do not know whether anyone knows the answer to this problem.

Comment: Are there any examples of graphs with at least 3 vertices where it's known to be possible?

Comment: Yes, for example a 4-cycle. Or a hypercube graph of any dimension. In general you can solve a single edge, and if you can solve two graphs ($G_1, G_2$) with the same number of vertices, you can solve the following graph: Take a copy of G_1, and G_2, and join their vertices by a perfect amtching arbitrarily.

Comment: I did a breadth-first search in Python. Starting with 0 on the vertices in the triangle and 1 on the remaining vertex, then an equillibrium is not reached within 26 moves (at which point 8 million inequivalent configurations had been reached). Worth noting: starting from the above configuration, the vertex which started at 1 will not remain as the node with the maximum value forever, which is what I based my proof strategies on.

Comment: Are any nontrivial results known? Is it possible for the complete graph on 5 vertices? Where can I read about the 8-cycle problem?

Comment: Well, no real nontrivial results are known. The "trivial" results known to me are (briefly) as follows:  You only have a chance to do graphs where the number of vertices is a power of two, as by averaging integers, you will only get diadic rationals. You can not do paths if everything is zero except an end of the path, because you "have monotonicity". You can not do stars, because if you "think backwards", you start from the uniform distribution, and after a "step back" you can not move.

Comment: Also note that if you can "win" from a configuration, then you can win from an other configuration where you added the same number to every vertex of teh configuration. The same holds with multiplication. (This might help with your computer program, as you can for example assume that you have 0 at a fixed vertex, and that all the vertices are integers.) I will give more information on the 8-cycle later, as I do not know the proof personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution follows, stop reading if you  want to figure it out yourself.

Order nodes so that the leaf comes first and its neighbour comes next.

Claim.  $1, 1, -1, -1$  cannot be balanced.

Proof. Suppose that in step $0$ we have the above and in step $n$, where $n$ is minimal, we have  $0, 0, 0, 0$.
In step $n-2$ we must have $a, -a, a, -a$ (or the last two reversed) for some $a\ne 0$.

Call an edge balanced if its two endnodes have equal weight. For $0<i<n$, there is no disjoint pair of balanced edges in step $i$ because $n$ is minimal. However,  there is a balanced edge in each step. Thus, by reverse induction on $i$, in steps $i = 0, 1,2,\dots, n-2$, each weight is an odd multiple of $a$. This is a contradiction for $i=1$ because the second weight is $0$. QED

Remark (generalizing one of Dániel Soltész's remarks): If you can solve graphs $G_1$, $\dots$, $G_{2^k}$, each with $2^l$ nodes, and also $H_1$, $\dots$, $H_{2^l}$, each with $2^k$ nodes, then you can glue these (in many ways) to get a graph on $2^{k+l}$ nodes which you can solve.